# How do you get data from google analytics -v4 for acquisitions - campaigns?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, acquisition

Can someone give an example of the query to be used?How do we access the acquisitions and then campaign data from that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to make an [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics) request with the `ga:newusers` metric and the `ga:source`, `ga:medium`, `ga:campaign`.

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "1174",
      "dateRanges": 
      [
        {
          "startDate": "2014-11-01",
          "endDate": "2014-11-30"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:newusers"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:campaign"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:source"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:medium"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And again in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/batchget/m/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet?_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522reportRequests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522viewId%2522%253A+%25221174%2522%252C%250A++++++%2522dateRanges%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522startDate%2522%253A+%25222014-11-01%2522%252C%250A++++++++++%2522endDate%2522%253A+%25222014-11-30%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522metrics%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522expression%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Anewusers%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522dimensions%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Acampaign%2522%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Asource%2522%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Amedium%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&).

The API also allows you to construct a [cohort request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts) to measure engagement overtime.

If you are new to Google's APIs, they make available many [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/libraries) as well as set of [quickstart guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/#quick_start_guides).

Comment: Thanks Matt! For anyone else looking for a solution, there is a dimension called ga:acquisitionCampaign which helps you get the acquisition-campaign data.